# How to make an unified interface for synchronous and asynchronous code in Python?

Tags: python, concurrency, python-asyncio

With a quick example, let's say I'd like to implement code for crawling some stock price data from a specific site. In a normal(synchronous) way, the code would be look like this:

```
import bs4
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession, HTMLSession


def get_response(site_url):
    session = HTMLSession()
    res = session.get(site_url)
    return res


def get_data_list(site_url, past_date):
    res = get_response(site_url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    item_elements = soup.select('item')

    price_dict_list = []
    for item_element in item_elements:
        date_time, open, high, low, close, volume = item_element.get('data').split('|')
        price_dict_list.append(
            {
                'date_time': date_time,
                'open': open,
                'high': high,
                'low': low,
                'close': close,
                'volume': volume
            }
        )
        if date_time == past_date:
            break
    return price_dict_list
```

But when I'd like to implement it in an async way, while keeping the synchronous code as well, an additional code would be ADDED like this:

```
import bs4
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession, HTMLSession


def get_response(site_url):
    session = HTMLSession()
    res = session.get(site_url)
    return res


def get_data_list(site_url, past_date):
    res = get_response(site_url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    item_elements = soup.select('item')

    price_dict_list = []
    for item_element in item_elements:
        date_time, open, high, low, close, volume = item_element.get('data').split('|')
        price_dict_list.append(
            {
                'date_time': date_time,
                'open': open,
                'high': high,
                'low': low,
                'close': close,
                'volume': volume
            }
        )
        if date_time == past_date:
            break
    return price_dict_list


async def get_response2(site_url):
    session = AsyncHTMLSession()
    res = await session.get(site_url)
    return res


def get_data_list2(site_url, past_date):
    res = await get_response2(site_url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    item_elements = soup.select('item')

    price_dict_list = []
    for item_element in item_elements:
        date_time, open, high, low, close, volume = item_element.get('data').split('|')
        price_dict_list.append(
            {
                'date_time': date_time,
                'open': open,
                'high': high,
                'low': low,
                'close': close,
                'volume': volume
            }
        )
        if date_time == past_date:
            break

    return price_dict_list
```

But as you can see, these two functions have duplicated codes except the part of creating a Session.
What annoying me is that every time I try to implement the code in both ways, I need to implement TWO functions and these functions always have duplicated logic.

What I want is a single interface like this:

- In testing through the IPython shell (or developing stage): call `get_data_list()`
- In production: call `await get_data_list()`
  I know this gonna be hard to implement, when considering how the asyncio works, but removing the duplicated logic will be enough for me.

Is there any idea to write an efficient code in this situation?

Comment: I asked the same question at some point, but sadly there isn't really a very satisfying answer. Have a look at the linked question. You'll effectively need to make a choice about which one you need and whether it's worth maintaining the "same" code twice for other use cases. In fact, as things get more complicated, you'll find that in the asynchronous case you'll sometimes deviate more from the synchronous version.

Comment: Mind you, it makes sense: asynchronous code should be designed with the idea of yielding control in mind, getting the most out of the available resource, while synchronous code tends to be designed in a way that optimises for order and thus efficiency in a very different way - knowing that everything will happen in a certain order is clearly very different from knowing the CPU will at least be doing something most of the time (on the one interpreter anyway)